# create a timer in multiple activity for android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, countdowntimer

i am using android studio kotlin and i want to create a countdown timer for multiple activities. for example, i am doing a quiz and the timer is ticking and i make a multiple quiz question in multiple activities. so the timer is display in multiple activities and continuous ticking until the timer runs out.

i have no idea how to do it because i am still a fresh learner

Answer (score 1):

you can change the design to have one Activity for the quiz as whole and have a Fragment for each question. The timer would live in the Activity. You can have the Activity layout to have a place for the timer shown and a FragmentContainerView for the part of screen, where you want to show the questions.

See https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments